# MySQL NULL field asking for value while INSERT

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1364

Mysql Version: 5.7.x

**Query:**

```
INSERT INTO `products_manufacturer`
   SET    `website_id` = 27,
          `name` = 'YAZAKI CORP',
          `url` = 'http://www.speclocator.com/mfg_category.php?manufacturename=YAZAKI+CORP',
          `enabled` = true,
          `rectified_manufacturer_id` = NULL,
          `logo` = NULL;
```

**Error Code:** 1364. Field 'facebook' doesn't have a default value 0.000 sec

Table Structure attached as screenshot.[image: DESC]

Comment: Please set the default value for facebook column AS 0.000

Comment: it is working fine for me.

Comment: facebook field is taking null value,no need to modify your query

Answer (score 0):

Try below query then after inserting data

```
ALTER TABLE products_manufacturer MODIFY COLUMN facebook VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT '0.000';
```

Comment: Yes, I can understand your thought. But it should not ask for value if field is defined as NULL.

Comment: Then you can try like this way

INSERT INTO `products_manufacturer`
   SET    `website_id` = 27,
          `name` = 'YAZAKI CORP',
          `url` = 'http://www.speclocator.com/mfg_category.php?manufacturename=YAZAKI+CORP',
          `enabled` = true,
          `rectified_manufacturer_id` = NULL,
          `logo` = NULL,
          `facebook` = '0.000';